# how to organize users to run the different part of a project?

Tags: django, web-applications

How do you organize your users to run the different part of your project? Is there a best practice?

For example, I use nginx, redis, gunicorn, supervisor to run my django app.

Is it better to have a user for each part (redis user for running redis, etc.) or only one user ("project_name") that runs all of them?

Comment: I use a user per-service I.e. nginx for nginx, redis for redis, appuser for the given app launched by supervisord

Answer (score 0):

This will depend somewhat on your OS.  There are no best-practice-django rules for user setup, only best-practice-operations for you OS.  I use Debian based Linux for my Django deploys.  For each of the services you mention I simply use the user that the OS defaults to (www-data for nginx, postgres for the database, redis for redis).  The only user I have to 'select' is the one running the app server (in my case I use uWSGI).  For convenience I use www-data.  You can make an appserver user and put it in the www-data group to resolve any permission conflicts between the frontend and the appserver.